# How to render html.erb file to assets/javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Below is the code I have in my `assets/javascripts/investment.js` file:

```
investment_updates.forEach(function(investment_update, n){
    data.push(new Item((n+1)*space, (n+1)*space, (n)*angle));
    add(n+1, "<%= render '/investment_updates/single_investment_update', investment_update: investment_update %>")
});
```

I want to render `views/investment_updates/_single_investment_update.html.erb` file in my javascript file and I tried below code but didn't work.

```
<%= render '/investment_updates/single_investment_update', investment_update: investment_update %>
```

Help me to render partial in my js file as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your `js` file should end in `.js.erb` instead, so it will be picked up by the Rails Asset Pipeline.

Note though that the way you are inserting data in a string is quite brittle. One misplaced `'` or `"` can break your Javascript